# Array of strings. Compiler error. Maybe memory out of bounds?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand the concept of array of char pointers in C.
In this basic example I try to get the number of strings using the x++ operator but, unfortunately I get a compiler error because maybe I try to access an extra region of memory but I shoudn't? Thanks for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *argv[]= {"hello","world"};
    int num = 0;

    while (argv[num++] != NULL){
        printf("num value: %i\t  %c\n",num,*argv[num-1]);
    }

    printf("Final num value: %i\n",num);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you say _compiler error_ , this is false, you have the error at the execution, please be careful when you describe your problem

Comment: pippo inzaghi "I get a compiler error " --> It is more informative to also post the exact text of that error.  That raises the value of this post as it is easier for others to find the same issue and for others to solve.

Comment: Both of You are correct, sorry. The error I was getting at execution time was `Cygwin Exception : open stack dump file`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are exceeding array bounds since

```
 while (argv[num++] != NULL)
```

will stop when `argv[num]` is `NULL`, yet `argv[]`'s dimension is `2`, and both entries are `!= NULL`.

You could write...

```
 char *argv[]= {"hello","world",NULL};
```

and it should work with your end condition as is.

BTW: you are aware that `argv[]` is often used as name for the parameters to function `main`, i.e. `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`, which represent the command line arguments when your program gets called, are you? When you use the function `main`-parameter, I think that the last valid element of it will by `NULL` by definition (cf., for example, [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p2) online C11 standard draft):

> **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
>
> ....
>
> (2) If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall
>   obey the following constraints:
>
> argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.

If you create your "own" local `argv[]`-thing, however, you have to do this explicitly on your own.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen anything specifying that argv is NULL terminated - hence the argc value is required.  Can you cite a source for that?

Comment: @Shawn That is explicitly in the C standard, § 5.1.2.2.1 (*Program Startup*): — argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.

Comment: @GovindParmar And a link:  [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p2)

Comment: Yes, I understand that _argv_ is a "reserved" word. But unfortunately I still don't understand what is causing the error in my code.
I understand that `argv[num]` will stop when it is  `NULL`.
I understand that `argv[]`'s dimension is `2` and that both entries are `!=NULL`.
But why am I getting an error?

Comment: `argv` isn't a reserved word. It just that when you define an array like `char* x[2]`, then `x[0]="a"` and `x[1]="b"`  are OK, but `x[2]="a"` exceeds array bounds. `char* argv[] = {"a","b"}` is equivalent to an array like `char* x[2]`. As `argv[num++]` with `num==1` will be `!= NULL`, `num` will be increased to `2` and will access the array out of its bounds in the next round then.

Comment: I understand now thank you. The reason why I called this array `argv` is because I am using it as parameters vector in `execv` and that caused further confusion.
Does the parameter vector in `execv` need to end with `NULL` just like for the `main()` function?

According to [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) it does.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to adhere to this convention and terminate the array passed to `execv` with an `NULL`-value.